# Is it possible to execute two react-native contexts in different threads?

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a native app written in swift, that's using react-native for some parts.

I have a first react-native view that's displaying items in a scroll view, and when I scroll in this scroll view some elements become visible and are rendered.

I have another react-native view, that's executing a loop of events every 500ms or so, and I need it to be precise enough.

```
import Editor from './src/components/Editor';
import Playback from './src/components/Playback';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Editor', () => Editor);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Playback', () => Playback);
```

The thing is when I scroll on the first view, the rendering of elements is making the second view processing too slow.

So I was wondering if the second view's javascript code could be executed in another thread, so that it is not impacted by the first view.

Is that possible?

Comment: web workers maybe?

Comment: @AlekseiMaide It's react-native on iOS, I don't think web workers are available... :/

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=webwork I think it says they are... also found this: https://github.com/devfd/react-native-workers maybe you can make use of it.....

Comment: @AlekseiMaide The first link is about web applications, my app is not executed in safari, it gets "compiled" into a native app, and therefore cannot use safari APIs. The second link is interesting though! I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually using `Timer.scheduledTimer` on the native side and I had to change the mode when adding it to the run loop so that it would run even when scroll views were processing. So my problem wasn't actually related to react-native `setTimeout`, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You have to instantiate a new `bridge` object to create a new JavaScript context (which lives in dedicated thread). Then you can use those different bridge objects for instantiating `RootView`s.

Comment: Figured it could be that when I took a look at the source code of https://github.com/devfd/react-native-workers, thank you for confirming!

Comment: Great! I also have to mention that instantiating another bridge is relatively expensive and memory consuming operation. You have to have a good reason to do it.